# MYSQL - Select specific value from a fetched array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a small problem and since I am very new to all this stuff, I was not successful on googling it, because I dont know the exact definitions for what I am looking for.

I have got a very simple database and I am getting all rows by this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['id']. " - ". $row['name'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Now, my question is: how do I filter the 2nd result? I thought something like this could work, but it doesnt:

```
$name2= $row['name'][2];
```

Is it even possible? Or do I have to write another mysql query (something like `SELECT .. WHERE id = "2"`) to get the name value in the second row?

What I am trying to is following:

-get all data from the database (with the "while loop"), but than individually display certain results on my page. For instance `echo("name in second row")` and `echo("id of first row")` and so on.

Comment: Do you want only the 2nd row, or you want to operate on the second row within the loop?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? There might be a better solution if you'd give a bit more background information.

Comment: I edited my question trying to explain what I would like to achieve. I hope its somehow understandable..

Comment: Do you want the second row returned by the query or the row that have `id=2`?

Comment: The query should basically return all rows, but I would than like to use them individually if thats possible as I tried to explain in my edit. I know I could do it by writing a new mysql query, but I thought that might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you would rather work with a full set of results instead of looping through them only once, you can put the whole result set to an array:

```
$row = array();

while( $row[] = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) );
```

Now you can access individual records using the first index, for example the name field of the second row is in `$row[ 2 ][ 'name' ]`.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry to ask another dumb question, but where exactly would I put your code? I tried it inside my existing loop and outside, but I keep getting "Undefined offset: 2".

Comment: Nevermind! I figured it out. I forgot the count starts at 0... but for some strange reason row[0] gives the 2nd row and row[1] still gives an undefined offset error, although I have 2 rows in my database, but this is probably related to another error in my code I guess.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ... WHERE 1=1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
/*This will loop arround all the Table*/
    if($row['id'] == 2){
    /*You can filtere here*/
    }

    echo $row['id']. " - ". $row['name'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that this works very nice too. Simple but effective, however I will go with Juhana´s answer once I figured what I am doing wrong there :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $counter++;

    if($counter == 2){
        echo $row['id']. " - ". $row['name'];
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: set initial value of $counter to -1, if id starts from 0. You can also change condition to check $row['id'] value. infact a lot of choices are there :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ideally you have to write another sql query to filter your results. If you had :

```
SELECT * FROM Employes
```

then you can filter it with :

```
SELECT * FROM Employes WHERE Name="Paul";
```

if you want every names that start with a P, you can achieve this with :

```
SELECT * FROM Employes WHERE Name LIKE "P%";
```

The main reason to use a sql query to filter your data is that the database manager systems like MySQL/MSSQL/Oracle/etc are highly optimized and they're way faster than a server-side  condition block in PHP.

Comment: I think you mean `.. WHERE Name LIKE "P%"`

Answer (score 0):

This While loop will automatically fetch all the records from the database.If you want to get any other field then you will only need to use for this.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do. mysql_fetch_array() fetches the current row to which the resource pointer is pointing right now. This means that you don't have `$row['name'][2];` at all. On each iteration of the while loop you have all the columns from your query in the $row array, you don't get all rows from the query in the array at once. If you need just this one row, then yes - add a `WHERE` clause to the query, don't retrieve the other rows if you don't need them. If you need all rows, but you wanna do something special when you get the second row, then you have to add a counter that checks which row you are currently working with. I.e.:

```
$count = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if(++$count == 2)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically the same as cidenix proposed and both would work, or did I missunderstand it?

Comment: Nope, it's not the same. Depends on what you want to do. @cidenix's code is checking the value of the id column returned by the query ($row['id'] == 2). I'm just incrementing a counter, which means that you get inside the if() when you reach the second returned row, regardless of it's values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use 2 consecutive results in one loop, you can store the results of the first loop, and then loop through.

```
$initial = true;
$storedId = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  $storedId = $row['id'];

  if($initial) {

    $initial = false;
    continue;
  }

  echo $storedId . $row['name'];
}
```

This only works for consecutive things though.Please excuse the syntax errors, i haven't programmed in PHP for a very long time...

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the second row, no matter how many rows you have in the database you should modify your query thus:

```
SELECT * FROM theTable LIMIT 1, 1;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

I used the code from the answer and slightly modified it. Thought I would share.

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT name FROM category;", db_connect() );
$myrow = array();
while ($myrow[]  = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC )) {}
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Example usage

```
echo "You're viewing " . $myrow[$view_cat]['name'] . "from a total of " . $num;
```