# Getting exact value from fetched array from MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Not a duplicate of [Select specific value from a fetched array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821203/mysql-select-specific-value-from-a-fetched-array)

I have a MySql database as:
[image]

Here's my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY Score DESC";
```

I want it to be a leaderboard which people can update their scores so I can't use

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY Score DESC WHERE ID = 1";
```

I want to get Username of the second row in my query.So I wrote:

```
<?php
include "l_connection.php";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY Score";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($result->num_rows>0){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

}
echo "Result = '".$row[1]['Username']."''";
}

?>
```

But it returns Result = '' like there's nothing in the array.

But if I write

```
if($result->num_rows>0){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "Name = '".$row['Username']."''";
}
}
```

It will return : Parham, Mojtaba, Gomnam, Masoud, 
So what am I doing wrong in the first snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access `$row` outside of while loop.

So store result in one new array, and then you can access that new array outside the while loop:

```
$newResult = array();
if($result->num_rows>0){
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      $newResult[] = $row;
  }
}

echo "Result = '".$newResult[1]['Username']."''"; // thus you can access second name from array
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you write where condition after ORDER by at

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY Score DESC WHERE ID = 1";
```

The sequence of query is

```
 SELECT * FROM data // select first
 WHERE ID = 1
 ORDER BY Score DESC// Order by at last
```

Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

And for second case you need to fetch `Username` inside while loop and use `$row['Username']` instead `$row[1]['Username']`

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   echo "Result = '".$row['Username']."''";// write inside while loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign row value to any array and use that array.

```
<?php
    include "l_connection.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY Score";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($result->num_rows>0){
        $rows = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        echo "Result = '".$rows[1]['Username']."'";
    }

?>
```

Or if you want only second highest score from column you can user limit as

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY Score limit 1,1";
```