# Getting a specific column and row from a fetched array

Tags: php

I have seen the answer for [MYSQL - Select specific value from a fetched array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821203/mysql-select-specific-value-from-a-fetched-array) but it is showing an error for me.

It says "Notice: Undefined offset: 1" at the echo line. I can't figure out what have i done wrong.

```
$qry = "Select Address, Phone from People where name='david'";

mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' , '' ,'database');

$result = mysqli_query(mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' , '' ,'database'), $qry);

mysqli_close(mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' , '' ,'database'));

$row = array();

while( $row[] = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) );

echo $row[1]['Address'];
echo $row[1]['Phone'];
```

Comment: I'm trying to store the result set in an array, then get the data i want by setting the row and column. Like $row[rowNumber][columnName]

Comment: I removed my comment, your `while()` loop is indeed correct, I didn't notice this statement, `$row = array();`. The problem is, you're closing the connection before `while()` loop. And there's no need to create a separate connection in each and every places, just create a connection and use the returned handler in the subsequent statements.

Comment: Don't assign to the array variable in the `while()` condition. You'll end up adding an extra element to the array containing the `false` value when you reach the end of the results. Use the normal idiom `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $rows[] = $row; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening 3 times the connection. PHP may read the wrong link to get your query. Try this :

```
$qry = "Select Address, Phone from People where name='david'";

$ptr = mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' , '' ,'database');

$result = mysqli_query($ptr, $qry);

$row = array();

while( $row[] = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) );

mysqli_close($ptr);

echo $row[1]['Address'];
echo $row[1]['Phone'];
```

Comment: Threw mysqli_close to the last line but still getting the same result.

Comment: @QiZhi May be it's returning one row from the result set, because of this `... where name='david'`. Do `var_dump($row);` and see what you're getting.

Comment: array (size=1)
  0 => null.

However I did :
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo $row2['Address']."<br>";
    }
and it returns 4 result.

Comment: So i guess there is something wrong in this line "while( $row[] = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) );" because there isn't 4 rows in the array?

Comment: maybe `$row` is a protected word in the first place !

Comment: i deleted the while loop that displays the result set and I have no idea why but it works now. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Index of php's array starts at 0. 
If there is only one result, or you want the first one, it will be at $row[0]

```
//displays the first line's result
echo $row[0]['Address'];
echo $row[0]['Phone'];
```

Comment: There is more than 1 row and even when i use $row[0] there is no output.